# flexbox not centering vertically on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a template using bootstrap and I am using a flexbox to vertically and horizontally center my landing page content. It looks fine on a desktop(chrome and firefox checked), but on mobile(chrome and safari checked) it floats to the top. I have searched the web but have not found a solution that has worked for me.

I have pasted in my code and the live version is at http://webcanvases.com/download-theme/theme/material-theme.html

HTML

```
<!-- Landing Page -->
<div class="video-bg vertical-center" id="page-top" data-vide-bg="mp4/traffic2">  
    <div class="jumbotron container text-center">
        <h1>Material World<br>Theme</h1> 
        <a data-scroll href="#about"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down animated bounce"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Landing Page End -->
```

CSS

```
.vertical-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.video-bg {
    height: 800px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Edit the post with browser version in your mobile.

Comment: may be the reason browser doesn't support `flex`

Comment: `.video-bg`height is set to a static value (800px). Try using `height : 100vh`

Comment: Blaze- I tried switching to 100vh but am still having the same issue.

Comment: Shehary- Chrome supports flexbox, but I tried prefixing my flexbox properties with -webkit- just to see if it might help but it didn't.

Answer (score -1):

It's not working because you have to set the flex properties on an outer container. Then the elements on the inside will follow the flex properties.

```css
.vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

.video-bg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center">
  <div class="video-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jared, thank you for your quick reply. I tried the code snippet, but it still does not vertically center on mobile. It floats to the top like the code I am currently using.